# Can any character be used in place of a backslash?

Tags: tex-core, syntax

In Chapter 3 of *The TeXbook*, Knuth writes:

> TeX allows any character to be used for escapes, but the “backslash” character ‘\’ is usually adopted for this purpose...

This has me confused, for I have never seen anything other than `\` used for escapes. Is this character configurable? If yes, how? Just curious.

Comment: look at texinfo format which uses @ or xmltex which has no escape or xii.tex which uses j

Comment: It is, in principle, configurable, but at this point in history, the TeX ecosystem is so heavily based around the use of the backslash that everything from your editor of choice to solutions from this site will probably fail if try to change it. And TeX error messages will still refer to commands using the backslash, and I’ve never heard of any way to change this (is there one, @DavidCarlisle?).

Comment: But to answer your question, just pick any character you would like to use (I take `@` as an example) and do ```\catcode`\@=0```.

Comment: @Gaussler this indeed works! And The TeXbook does indeed explain it.

Comment: In the 1980`s in Sweden a system "SweTeX" was used where `/` was used for escapes. That was with ISO-646-SE text files where `ÄÖÅäöå` were used instead of `[\]{|}` (so some additional changes were made as well).

Comment: @pst Interesting. How do you know this?

Comment: @Gaussler tex messages will not use `\\ ` if it is not catcode 0.  this gives `! Undefined control sequence.
l.6 jqqqqq` ... `\catcode\`j=0
\catcode\`\\=12


jqqqqq

jbye`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You are right, turns out I was thinking not of error messages, but of operations like `\show`. I just tried doing `@show@begin`. It yielded `> \begin=macro:
->\protect \begin  .
l.9 @show@begin`.

Comment: @Atom If you mean you would like some sources for that, maybe there will be after I asked about it at  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/691255/  .

Comment: perhaps this should be tagged `tex-core` instead of (or besides) `plain-tex` because all formats AFAIK already start with backslash having catcode 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm...

```
%% Abandon all hope, ye who enter here …
\begingroup % Let's limit damage
    \catcode`\@=0
    @def@yay{look, a cs!}

    Hello, world! @yay
\endgroup
\bye
```

(So you see that now that `\` and `@` are equivalent). Probably will make LaTeX explode in curious ways...

Comment: Ah, nice... is that some kind of "official English translation" of the phrase?

Comment: OT, but the translation is explained here:  https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abandon_hope_all_ye_who_enter_here

Comment: Infatti, io studiando italiano questi oggi!